# Why am I getting a runtime error / key error "no device found for" empty device address?

Tags: linux, gnuradio

Why am I getting the following error message when executing uhd_fft GNU Radio script:

```
/opt/gnuradio-3.7.1git/bin$ uhd_fft 
linux; GNU C++ version 4.6.3; Boost_104601; UHD_003.005.003-123-g1c391767

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/gnuradio-3.7.1git/bin/uhd_fft", line 341, in <module>
    main ()
  File "/opt/gnuradio-3.7.1git/bin/uhd_fft", line 337, in main
    app = stdgui2.stdapp(app_top_block, "UHD FFT", nstatus=1)
  File "/opt/gnuradio-3.7.1git/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/wxgui/stdgui2.py", line 38, in __init__
    wx.App.__init__ (self, redirect=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 7981, in __init__
    self._BootstrapApp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 7555, in _BootstrapApp
    return _core_.PyApp__BootstrapApp(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/gnuradio-3.7.1git/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/wxgui/stdgui2.py", line 42, in OnInit
    self._max_noutput_items)
  File "/opt/gnuradio-3.7.1git/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/wxgui/stdgui2.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.panel = stdpanel (self, self, top_block_maker, max_nouts)
  File "/opt/gnuradio-3.7.1git/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/wxgui/stdgui2.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.top_block = top_block_maker (frame, self, vbox, sys.argv)
  File "/opt/gnuradio-3.7.1git/bin/uhd_fft", line 91, in __init__
    otw_format=options.wire_format, args=options.stream_args))
  File "/opt/gnuradio-3.7.1git/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/uhd/__init__.py", line 121, in constructor_interceptor
    return old_constructor(*args)
  File "/opt/gnuradio-3.7.1git/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/uhd/uhd_swig.py", line 1700, in make
    return _uhd_swig.usrp_source_make(*args)
RuntimeError: LookupError: KeyError: No devices found for ----->
Empty Device Address
```

I'm using [BladeRF hardware](http://nuand.com/) and followed [these instructions](http://nuand.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2804).

I have gone through the recommendations listed here but UHD_FFT still can't seem to find the BladeRF even though

```
ls -lrt /dev | grep blade
crw-------  1 root root    180,   0 Aug 11 14:04 bladerf0
```

Why would my device not be found by UHD_FFT even though linux is aware of its existence ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your BladeRF is only accessible by the root user. To fix this make a udev rule file (I know the write up you followed earlier had you do something similar, but bear with me). This will allow your regular user account to access it. You can start in the shell by typing:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/15-bladerf
```

This should make a new file and open the nano editor. Here you will place the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="1d50", SYSFS{idProduct}=="6066", MODE="0666"
```

Afterwards, reset the udev rules service by executing:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

NOTE: This commands should work on any Debian-based OS (Debian, Ubuntu, Linux Mint,...)

CREDIT: The udev rules were found here http://pastebin.com/Mgb90L1x